# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE while making ajax request from node-webkit

Tags: jquery, ajax, https, node-webkit

when I'm trying to make ajax request with jquery to:

```
https://localhost:8443/uri
```

I get this error:

```
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

I'm using self signed certificate, in package.json I have these parameters:

```
"chromium-args": "--ignore-certificate-errors --auth-schemes='basic --auth-server-whitelist='*localhost:8443' --auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist='*localhost:8443'''",
```

does anybody know how I can add self signed certificates to node-webkit's truststore !?

OS: ubuntu 14.10

Comment: my guess is your browser is blocking https domain not having certificate.

Comment: see if this help https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example

Comment: did you enable CORS? @Rodislav could you add your ajax call?

Comment: Does [this question on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list) help?

Comment: it seems that this answer solve the isse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504827/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response-socket-io

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the browser is blocking the call to that server because that server has an invalid certificate.  Since it is a localhost server, it is a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).  The best way to get around this is to try one of the following...

- Change the localhost:8443 server to use a [valid certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/)
- From your browser load the page, https://localhost:8443/, accept the invalid certificate, and then try the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) call.

Comment: Manually accessing the page and accepting the invalid certificate helped me eliminate the error message, although it doesn't fix my problem since this won't be an option for those using my client. This isn't a thing which needs security, but because it's being called from a secure page, it will only work if also secure. And this is only a toy - a pricey official certificate is out of the question... Help!?

Comment: cant create certificate for localhost  -https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: The second point saved my time :) appreciated