# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, pki

I'm using a wildcard certificate under apache2 and nodejs simultaneously.
Sometimes (**not always**), when some clients try to connect to nodejs they get net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE.

I'm using the same certificate .key, .ca etc either for apache2 and nodejs.
The only difference is that nodejs uses port 8080 instead of the standard 443. It could be a problem? I can't spot why it happens only sometimes and not always.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Still an issue unfortunately

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504827/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response-socket-io